# drop down having undefined as value

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp:DropDownList and after filling,  i want to make the first element to be Select or --Depart -- value
Following code has been added for the same

```
  ddlOri.DataBind();
  ddlOri.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
  ddlOri.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

For the second one , i tried with

```
  ddlDes.DataBind();

  ddlDes.Items.Insert(0, "");
```

[image]

What i found is that there is something called undefined 
Here is the drop down filling code

```
 public static void PopulateIBEPortsDropDownList(DropDownList dropDown, string placeholder)
{
     dropDown.Attributes.Add("data-placeholder", placeholder);
     dropDown.Attributes.Add("data-autocomplete", "True");
     dropDown.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
     var thisPortList = InitialisePortList();

     foreach (var port in thisPortList)
    {
      dropDown.Items.Add(port);
    }

    dropDown.DataTextField = "Text";
    dropDown.DataValueField = "Value";
  }
```

Can some one point my mistake

Comment: dropDown binds to a keyvaluepair . Check if port in thisPortList has an undefined value.

Comment: undefined came after i add `  ddlOri.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
  ddlOri.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: is thisPortList a dictionary object ?

Comment: this is  a List<ListItem>